# Hover effect on IE10

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, sass, internet-explorer-10

I cannot understand why a simple hover effect on a div won't work in IE10.

CSS:

```
.portfolio {
    margin-bottom: 130px;
    .portfolioContainer {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        margin-left: -10px;
        margin-right: -10px;
        .portfolioBox {
            display: flex;
            width: 50%;
            height: 250px;
            padding: 10px;
            .moreBoxInfo {
                display: none;
            }
            .portfolioBoxLogo {
                width: 50%;
                background-color: $lighter_gray;
                display: flex;
                align-items: center;
                justify-content: center;
                padding: 5px;
                img {
                    display: block;
                    transform: scale(0.8);
                    max-width: 90%;
                    width: 100%;
                }
            }
            .portfolioBoxImg {
                width: 50%;
                background-position: center;
                background-size: cover;
                position: relative;
                cursor: pointer;
                &:before {
                    content: '';
                    position: absolute;
                    top: 0;
                    left: 0;
                    width: 100%;
                    height: 100%;
                    background: $primary;
                    opacity: 0;
                    transition: opacity .5s;
                    z-index: 1;
                }
                .portfolioBoxText {
                    position: absolute;
                    top: 0;
                    left: 0;
                    width: 100%;
                    height: 100%;
                    padding: 20px;
                    opacity: 0;
                    transition: opacity .5s;
                    z-index: 2;
                    p {
                        font-size: 16px;
                        line-height: 20px;
                        text-align: left;
                    }
                }
                .more {
                    position: absolute;
                    right: 20px;
                    bottom: 20px;
                    @include fontFamilySize("HelveticaNeueThin", 36px, 42px);
                    cursor: pointer;
                    display: none;
                    z-index: 3;
                }
                &:hover {
                    &:before {
                        opacity: .95;
                    }
                    .portfolioBoxText {
                        opacity: 1;
                    }
                    .more {
                        display: block;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="portfolio">
    <div class="portfolioContainer">
        <div class="portfolioBox">
            <div style="background-image: url( img/participadas/forcemanager-img.jpg)" class="portfolioBoxImg">
                <div class="portfolioBoxText"> 
                    <p>Aplicació per accelerar les vendes en equips comercials basada en Intel·ligència Artificial.</p>
                </div>
                <span class="more">+</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This SASS code compiles perfectly well.

The expected working code should be that when I hover the `div.portfilioBoxImg`, the `:before`, `.more` and `.portfolioBoxText` should gain `opacity: 1`, but it won't work.

I have other hovers around the site, and they work fine, but this one doesn't.

I tried getting rid of transition, without opacity and adding display none/block, but those works on themselves, what it doesn't works is the hover effect.

Compiled CSS extracted from chrome:

`.portfolio .portfolioContainer .portfolioBox .portfolioBoxImg:before`

This works perfectly on IE11, Firefox, chrome...

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vy5npu3a/

**EDIT**

I tried a hover within the body with the ::before, and it doesn't works either, but with an anchor `a` it does. Maybe some elements don't work?

Comment: Add your html too

Comment: @Viira added, and the css from the before pseudo class. html updated to match actual.

Comment: seems to be a lot of issue in your scss file can you fork'em up in a codepen or a jsfiddle?

Comment: @Viiraa added jsfiddle

Comment: The SASS code may compile well, but it generates some ugly CSS. You really don't need all that nesting.

Comment: `:before` should be `::before`, really. All the pseudo-elements are meant to be delimited by double colons.

Comment: @Tomalak i tried that too. but even the `portfolioboxtext` doesn't shows up.

Comment: Well, debugging 101. Dumb it down. Keep removing things until it starts to work. Identify the one detail that breaks it.

Comment: @Tomalak I tried adding a hover to the body, just to check out. IE10 doesn't works for me at least while chrome it does.

Comment: @Spudley it's just because i like to have components that can be reused with it's own css. anyways, I tried a new div, with a hover and before, and doesn't works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The doctype html was missing. I can swear i had try it before without success, but seems like now works.

Comment: If that works then try to mark your own last post as an answer will help to close this thread.